# Should I build a physics engine for my game, or use an already made one

Tags: java, android, physics, game-physics

I am planning on making a game for Android with some 2d rope physics. The core mechanic involves dragging strings around an environment. This is basically the extent of the physics in the game, at least the physics that I want to look reasonably realistic.

I haven't taken a physics class and I only know math up to high school trigonometry. Is a mechanic like this too difficult to code myself after some research? Should I use a library like toxiclibs or Box2D?

I know it's irritating to ask a question that can't be directly answered, but I just want to weight the pros and cons of building something myself as opposed to using something that might be more refined.

Thanks

Comment: This might be better to ask on gamedevelopment.stackexchange.com (I seem to recall reading a popular question about implementing a worms-style "ninja rope" over there).

Comment: Use one thats already out there. Why waste time unless that is your end goal.

Comment: @Dustin It might be valuable to learn how to build a simple engine if that's within the realm of possibility. I just want to know if spring physics are a lot more complicated than I think.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said "If that is your end goal". Otherwise, look at how existing ones work then give your owna  shot.

Comment: Only you can answer if 'spring physics' are more complicated than you think.  The developers of Angry Birds used someone else's physics engine;  they've made a lot of money out of it, but I'm not sure the engine developers have made a single penny.  So it depends what you want to do, and why.

Comment: @Poldie Good point. My time would be better spent building the game itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Box2D.

- It has a stable port for android/java.
- Its well documented.
- Heaps of android samples and tutorials and blogs to support it.
- Wide tool support.
- It's also a popular physics engine on other platforms such as iPhone. so in theory it would be easier to port your games and reuse your skills!

I would also consider looking at [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). this is a whole android games framework build on top of box2d and open GL with a heap of features.